# Search for similarity of a mesh within another?

Tags: python, geometry, mesh, geometry-surface

First of all, sorry if this is rather basic but it is certainly not my field of expertise.

So, I'm working with protein surface and I have this cavity:

[Protein cavity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fAkmd.png)

It is part of a larger, watertight, triangular mesh (.ply format) that represents a protein surface.

What I want to do, is find whether this particular "sub-mesh" is found in other proteins. However, **I'm not looking for a perfect fit**, rather similar "sub-meshes" since the only place I will find this exact shape is in the original protein.

I've been reading the docs for the Python modules trimesh and open3d. Trimesh does have a comparison module, but it doesn't seem to have the functionality I'm looking for. Also, open3d has a "compute point cloud distance" function that is recommended to compare the difference between two point cloud or meshes.

However, since what I'm actually trying to find is similarity, I would need a way to fit my cavity's "sub-mesh" onto the surface of the protein I'm analyzing, and then "score" how different or deformed the fitted submesh is. Another way would be to rotate and translate my sub-mesh to match the most vertices and faces on the protein surface and score that I guess.

Just a heads-up, I'm a biotechnologist, self-taught in Python and with extremely limited experience in anything 3D. At this point, anything helps, be it a paper, Python module or whatever knowledge you have that you think might be useful.

Thank you very much for any help you can provide with this!